# Router bandwitch vs ISP bandwith

Tags: wireless-networking, bandwidth, isp

when I am using a router for example of 300Mbps, and i have a download speed of 100Mbps and 25 Mbps of upload, when i am connecting to internet, is this speed affecting my lan bandwidth? for example, if i download something at a rate of 100Mbps, would I be using 200Mbps of my router bandwidth? (100 from isp and 100 to my machine) ?

Comment: bandwidth is the capacity to carry data as measured across a link for a point in time. in my case, I have a 400Mb/s Internet connection, but my LAN runs at 1Gb/s. so when i download from the internet, if I'm connected to a really fast server with good connectivity, I will consume at most 400Mb/s from the ISP link. that same 400Mb/s will be required to send the data from my router to my device, but don't think about it like its cumulative. I'm still only using 400Mb/s of bandwidth on any given link at any given time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router bandwidth usually talks about how fast of a connection to your ISP the router can handle.

It doesn't usually talk about the switch side bandwith. Most switches can handle a "reasonable" amount of bandwidth across the switch ports. My router, for example has an 8 port switch in the back of it and can handle 10Gbps of switching traffic. That's less than full bandwith (8 ports * 1Gbps * 2 directions) but that isn't unusual.

So, to answer your question, if you were downloading something at 100Mpbs from the internet and transferring a file at 100Mpbs to another machine on your network, you would be using 200Mbps of switching bandwidth but only 100Mbps of the 300Mpbs your router can handle.

Now some routers throw bandwidth numbers around, some referring to WIFI bandwidth and others referring to "maximum internet bandwidth" (which is really NAT performance) so I'd need to know what model router to give you a definite answer, but I'm pretty sure this is all correct for your particular case.

Comment: okey so generally the bandwidth of the router is only local and ISP is not added to this, so if i download a game i wouldn't be using local bandwidth? but yes switching bandwidth ?

Comment: I probably went a little technical. But if you download a game from the internet it will be using both ISP and local, because it comes in the router, using say 100Mbps, and goes out the switch port, using 100Mbps of switching bandwidth. 

It will only count the 100Mbps with your ISP they don't see the internal bandwidth usage.

Likewise if you are transferring at 100Mbps from one machine to the other on the lan, it will use 0Mbps of your ISP bandwidth and 100Mbps of your switching bandwidth.

Comment: right because it have to transfer data from router to the machine too. Also by switching bandwidth you mean local + network right ? thanks you!